# ethereumjs-tx parameters for parity network

Tags: ethereum, parity

I am using ethereumjs-tx, example below is to the rospten test net:

```
const EthereumTx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;

const rawTx = {
            "from": sender,
            "nonce": "0x" + count.toString(16),
            "gasPrice": "0x003B9ACA00",
            "gasLimit": "0x250CA",
            "to": "0x3f84d0ca3529fbe8c2b...",
            "value": "0x0",
            "data": data,
            "chainId": 0x03
        };
const tx = new EthereumTx(rawTx, {'chain':'ropsten'});
```

What are the parameters I have to pass for parity private net?

1. `"chainId": 0x03`
2. `{'chain':'ropsten'}`